# Batch optimistic locking queries in EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, optimistic-locking

We have a codebase with JPA entities, each of which has a `long` field annotated with `@Version`. Over the course of a transaction, optimistic locks are grabbed on some entities with `entityManager.lock(entity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC)`, and so when the transaction commits EclipseLink runs queries of the following form:

```
UPDATE <table> SET VERSION = <x> where ((ID = <y>) AND (VERSION = <x>));
```

where `y` is the entity's ID and `x` is the current version number (it doesn't get updated). However, for some reason it's running each query individually, like so (from the MySQL logs):

```
UPDATE TableA SET VERSION = 5 WHERE ((ID = 1) AND (VERSION = 5));
UPDATE TableA SET VERSION = 4 WHERE ((ID = 2) AND (VERSION = 4));
UPDATE TableA SET VERSION = 3 WHERE ((ID = 3) AND (VERSION = 3));
UPDATE TableA SET VERSION = 2 WHERE ((ID = 4) AND (VERSION = 2));
UPDATE TableA SET VERSION = 1 WHERE ((ID = 5) AND (VERSION = 1));
-- etc
```

Whereas we would want all of the queries for the same table to be batched up into one `UPDATE`.

Is there some flag somewhere that we need to set to enable this? A typical transaction can generate hundreds of these queries for the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Batch writing is configured using the ["eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing"](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_jdbc_batchwriting.htm) persistence property. You might still not get this to change the optimistic lock statements though, as it depends on your driver and EclipseLink DB platform class: the code needs to determine which statement failed if there is an issue so that it may indicate which object was involved in the thrown OptimisticLockException.

Comment: Yeah, we already have this configured. I fear you may be right in that there's no way to batch optimistic lock statements.